# Need only 2 digits after decimal point

Tags: c#, format

I want my function to return value with *only 2 decimal places*. I have tried following code :

```
private static double CalculateSlabTax(int nSlabStartTaxable, 
                                       int nSlabEndTaxable, 
                                       float fSlabRate)
{
    double dblSlabResult = 0;
    try
    {
        dblSlabResult = (nSlabStartTaxable - nSlabEndTaxable) * fSlabRate;
        dblSlabResult = Math.Round(dblSlabResult , 2);
        return dblSlabResult;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Expected output is : `dblSlabResult = ####.##` - *two digits* (eg. `1002.05`)

Getting output as : eg. `dblSlabResult = 1002.1`

Comment: Is it possible that the number you got was something like `1002.101`? Then, rounded to two digits, `1002.1` is the expected result. Your method of calculation is correct.

Comment: Show inputs. Also that try/catch is pointless.

Comment: @harold inputs are in method parameter and try catch is not pointless

Comment: @DhirajSardal but what are they specifically. You did get only 2 digits after all, 1 is also a form of "only 2". The try/catch is only catching a wrong number of digits specified to `Math.Round`, which can never happen.

Comment: I think what @Harold meant by "Show inputs" is show some example values you are actually passing in.

Comment: For more help on formatting see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Dhiraj Sardal The try catch you have now is something I would not do. If you are returning -1, you don't know what went wrong, and the stack trace is swallowed; also, you are not forcing the user to handle exceptions. It's better to throw an exception that tells the consumer of your function what went wrong. Read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159096/return-magic-value-throw-exception-or-return-false-on-failure.

Comment: The only Exception to be thrown in `Math.Round(double value, int digits)` is `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for `digits` not being in `[0, 15]`. So with a static number input for `digits`, this should be neither `-1` nor an `Exception` for the consumer, but just a working piece of code without try-catch.

Comment: @grek40 Not really, you have to look at the (business) function itself, not only what can go wrong with (technical function) Math.Round; for example, if you pass invalid values the consumer should be aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple. Try this

```
public double UptoTwoDecimalPoints(double num)
{
    var totalCost = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.00}", num));
    return totalCost;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To *represent* use *formatting*. In your case exactly two digits after decimal point means `"F2"` format string

```
 double source = 1234.56789;
 // 1234.57
 var result = source.ToString("F2");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#` character is an optional digit placeholder. Use `0` to enforce digits when converting to string:

```
string.Format("{0:#.##}", 1002.1) == "1002.1"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 1002.1) == "1002.10"
```

Don't expect a specific count of digits when rounding `float` or `double`. They are just numbers, independent of their string format.

Answer (score 0):

What inputs are you using? Math.Round should be working correctly, which suggests that the line above is returning a double with only 1 significant figure.